# How to add click event to table row using Dojo

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I have a table like this:

```
<table class="thisTable">
    <tr>
        <td class="firstColumn"><a href="somepage.html">First</a></td>
        <td>Apple</td>
        <td>Ant</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="firstColumn"><a href="somepage2.html">Second</a></td>
        <td>Banana</td>
        <td>Bear</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="firstColumn"><a href="somepage3.html">Third</a></td>
        <td>Citrus</td>
        <td>Cat</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What I wanted to do is to be able to click the link in td.firstColumn even if I click on the other cells in the same row. How do I do this in Dojo? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the rows a unique class name, then query the domNode and add connect's to them with a loop.

```
var that = this;
dojo.query('rowClass', this.domNode).forEach(function (node, index, arr) {
    dojo.connect(node, "onclick", function (evt) {
        that.handleEvent(evt);
    });
});
```